# How to change the package name of R

Tags: r

I made a small change to the igraph package and want to install this changed package. But I have already installed the raw igraph package in computer before. These two packages have the same name.

I tried to change the name in the DESCRIPTION file from *igraph* to *igraphmy*. But it did not work. As the error shows:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'igraphmy', details:
  call: library.dynam("igraph", pkgname, libname, local = FALSE)
  error: DLL 'igraph' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `igraph` package contains C and other non-R code. This code is either compiles (if you are on Linux) when you do the install or you download pre-compiled binary files from CRAN (Mac and Windows). These C and C++ functions interface with R via `.Call`. The R function `.Call` includes as an argument the package name, `igraph`. So what happens is you load try to `igraphmy` and it fails because it can't find the functions in the `igraph` package that it wants because `igraph` isn't an existing package. Try loading `igraph` and then `igraphmy` or editing the `DESCRIPTION` to say that `igraphmy` depends on `igraph` and using the syntax `igraphmy::foo` to use the `igraphmy` version of a function and `igraph::foo` for the `igraph` verison.